# Sharepoint online archive Options

Tags: sharepoint-online, archive

I want to know the out of the box Sharepoint online archive Options.

1. If we want to move Sharepoint on-premises sites to Sharepoint online archive sites what and all options are there ?
2. Is there any 3-rd party tool ?
3. If we move Sharepoint on-premises site collection to subsites in Sharepoint online what is pros and Cons ?
4. Possible to move Sharepoint onprem site to Azure blob ?

Can you provide me the available options in Sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

1.Create and apply information management policies for the library.

Reference:
[Create and apply information management policies](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-eb501fe9-2ef6-4150-945a-65a6451ee9e9)

2.Configure in place records management.

Reference:
[Configure in place records management](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configuring-in-place-records-management-7707a878-780c-4be6-9cb0-9718ecde050a)

3.SharePoint archive tools like [Vyapin Dockit](https://www.vyapin.com/products/dockit-archiver) Archiver which provides so many out of the box archiving features.

Answer (score 0):

3. In SP Online you need to keep your site collections as site collections, don't make them sub-sites.  This is needed for the modern hub site architecture in SPO.  I typically recommend promoting your subsite to site collections during an On-prem to online migration.
4. Not sure what you are looking for here, but some migration tools, like ShareGate etc., use Azure blob storage to speed up the migration process.  If you are asking if you can store a SP site in Azure Blob storage, you can't do that.  But you could store a backup from SharePoint, or a database backup in Azure Blob storage, but you would need a on-prem / azure farm to restore to.